# Default Wordpress widgets always appear

Tags: widgets, widget-text

I added only 3 Widgets to my sidebar, however when I set their visibility to hidden in post pages they disappear but ALL the default widgets appear. I want to remove the default widgets from appearing because I don't want any widgets on my post page. Here is the code that makes all the default widgets appear.

```
<div class="widget widget_search widget-widget_search">
  <div class="widget-wrap widget-inside">
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="widget widget_pages widget-widget_pages">
  <div class="widget-wrap widget-inside">
    <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Pages', 'alkane' ); ?></h3>
      <ul><?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?></ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="widget widget_categories widget-widget_categories">
  <div class="widget-wrap widget-inside">
    <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Categories', 'alkane' ); ?></h3>
      <ul><?php wp_list_categories('title_li='); ?></ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="widget widget_archive widget-widget_archive">
  <div class="widget-wrap widget-inside">
    <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Archives', 'alkane' ); ?></h3>
      <ul><?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?></ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="widget widget_calendar widget-widget_calendar">
  <div class="widget-wrap widget-inside">
    <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Calendar', 'alkane' ); ?></h3>
    <?php get_calendar(); ?>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="widget widget_recent_entries widget-widget_recent_entries">
  <div class="widget-wrap widget-inside">
    <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Recent Posts', 'alkane' ); ?></h3>
      <ul><?php wp_get_archives('type=postbypost&limit=5'); ?></ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="widget widget_tag_cloud widget-widget_tag_cloud">
  <div class="widget-wrap widget-inside">
    <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Tag Cloud', 'alkane' ); ?></h3>
    <?php wp_tag_cloud('smallest=10&largest=20&number=30&unit=px&format=flat&orderby=name'); ?>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="widget widget_text widget-widget_text">
  <div class="widget-wrap widget-inside">
    <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'About Alkane', 'alkane' ); ?></h3>
    <div class="textwidget"><?php printf( __( '%s', 'alkane' ), $alkane_theme_data['Description'] ); ?></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="widget widget_links widget-widget_links">
  <div class="widget-wrap widget-inside">
    <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Blogroll', 'alkane' ); ?></h3>
      <ul><?php wp_list_bookmarks('title_li=&categorize=0'); ?></ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="widget widget_meta widget-widget_meta">
  <div class="widget-wrap widget-inside">
    <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Meta', 'alkane' ); ?></h3>
      <ul>
        <?php wp_register(); ?>
        <li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>
        <li><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'rss2_url' ); ?>" title="Syndicate this site using RSS 2.0">Entries <abbr title="Really Simple Syndication">RSS</abbr></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'comments_rss2_url' ); ?>" title="The latest comments to all posts in RSS">Comments <abbr title="Really Simple Syndication">RSS</abbr></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://wordpress.org/" title="Powered by WordPress, state-of-the-art semantic personal publishing platform.">WordPress.org</a></li>
        <?php wp_meta(); ?>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: theme details?
Are they set as default widgets by code or they are there in widgets?

Comment: I found out how to do it myself I just had to delete the static widgets with help from this website of course I looked at some previous questions.

Comment: Gr8 :), you can answer your question and mark it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted the lines of code I mentioned above and only left the remaining code in sidebar.php. The problem was they were hard coded so they appear if visibility is set to hidden to the sidebar widgets.